# Cannot connect to Strong ciphers TLS 1.2 from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, nginx, ssl

I just removed weak ciphers from my `nginx proxy server`

I applied this ciphers only in my nginx

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  off;
```

After I removed the weak ciphers, my asp.net application cannot connect to the server. even when I tried from my local computer, I still cannot connect to it. it will return the error message of

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I've tried to force my application to only use TLS 1.2 by

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But it still not working.

How should I edit my application so that it can connect to the strong ciphers server?

Here is some additional info :

- Can send a request successfully through postman, but not through ASP.NET application
- ASP.Net version is 4.6.1
- Running on Windows 10

Comment: "ASP.Net version is 4.6.1" <-- That is an incredibly old version of .NET you're targeting there - I don't believe there is any legitimate reason for anyone to target anything older than .NET 4.8 now. Anyway, [you **need** to be on .NET 4.7 or later to get the latest TLS changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls).

Comment: Thank you. Will upgrade our asp.net version then

Comment: We had a similar issue where stripe API was not working on Asp.Net 4.5.2 
Try adding ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

Comment: @GauravChaudhary your solution doesnt work. I have tried it. the solution from Dai works from me. I need to upgrade my asp.net framework version, then it works fine.